# Probability we found maximum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have random variables $ X_1,...,X_n $ (we do not know distribution). I want to know probability of following:
$ P(max\{ X_1,...,X_t \} > max\{ X_{t+1},...,X_n \}) $.
Why? In time $t$ I have observed $X_1,...,X_t$ and I want to know probability I have already maximum.

Comment: are these random variables independent? have markov property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_i$ are continuous and i.i.d., then the max is equally likely to be in any of the positions $1,2,\ldots,n$, so your probability is simply $\frac{t}{n}$. If $P(X_i=X_j)>0$ (e.g. discrete random variables), then it requires special care.